# GetCommState == false

Tags: c++-cli, usb

Работаю с Usb девайсом, GetCommState(ConDevice, &dcb); возвращает ноль , dcb структура пуста

```
BOOL CreateDevice(wchar_t* portname)
{
    n = portname;
    /*  ConDevice = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)name,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    CREATE_NEW,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);*/

    ConDevice = CreateFile(portname,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,

        NULL);
    if (ConDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        connectedStatus = false;
        return false;

    }

    SetupComm(ConDevice, inBufSize, inBufSize);
    //очистка мусора порта
    PurgeComm(ConDevice, PURGE_RXCLEAR);
    //Крнфигурация порта
    bool i = GetCommState(ConDevice, &dcb);
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
    dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
    dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
    dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
    dcb.fNull = FALSE;
    dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
    dcb.fAbortOnError = FALSE;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    SetCommState(ConDevice, &dcb);


    // Установка таймаута
    COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeOuts;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 100;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 100;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;
    CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 100;
    CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;
    SetCommTimeouts(ConDevice, &CommTimeOuts);

    connectedStatus = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: У вас нет инициализации DCB перед вызовом GetCommState. Ну и отдельно - нет GetLastError при ошибке в GetCommState, как и проверки статуса.

Comment: Уже как только не пробовал всеравно возвращает false